# Can we create a table in Azure SQL pool that contain a autoincrement column?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-synapse

I want to create a table that should contain an Id column that starts from 1 and goes to 1 increment like 1,2,3,4....n there is a functioning identity but in synapse Pool, it does not work for autoincrement sequentially.
Is there any other function available in Azure SQL Pool

Comment: This isn't a "problem" with Azure Synapse, it's your misunderstanding of `IDENTITY`; it has *never* been guaranteed to be sequential. Even a `SEQUENCE` doesn't completely alleviate this as rows can still be deleted and `INSERT` statements can fail when you request the next value from it. If you want a sequential value, then using something like `ROW_NUMBER` at the point of `SELECT`ing the data can often be a better option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Soluntion1:**
If we want a sequential value, then using something like `ROW_NUMBER()OVER(partition by <Grouping_field> ,order by <Sort_field> )`  at the point of `SELECT`ing the data.

---

**Soluntion2:**

As this [post](https://learn.microsoft.com/answers/answers/73495/view.html) says, we can use a table to store the Identity column value. Take the max(id) column and incrementing before inserting the data into a column every time.

```sql
 DECLARE @MaxRowId int
 SET @MaxRowId = (SELECT ISNULL(MAX(id),0)+1 FROM dbo.test)
```

Comment: I have used Row_Number for my use case.